# which elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ give the entire ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Which a ∈ $\mathbb{Z}_n$ satisfy 〈a〉$_\mathbb{Zn}$=$\mathbb{Z}_n$

From other theorems I'm thinking that $a_n$ must be a unit, but I don't know how to prove it... or if that is even correct.

Comment: Do you want $a$ to generate $\Bbb{Z}_n$ as a subgroup or as an ideal. If you want it to generate as an ideal, it's generally true that $aR=R$ if and only if $a$ is a unit. If you want it as an abelian group, it's still true, and the proof is that the abelian group generated by $a$ is $\Bbb{Z}a$, and since $\Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{Z}_n$ is surjective, $\Bbb{Z}a=a\Bbb{Z}_n$, so in this case it is equivalent to the ring case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean $\langle a\rangle$ as an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$.

Let's say $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is a unit, so it has a multiplicative inverse $a^{-1}$. Then, $\langle a \rangle a^{-1} \subseteq \langle a \rangle$, so we have $1 \in \langle a \rangle$. But then $\langle a \rangle = \langle 1 \rangle = \mathbb{Z}_{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there’s a very nice proof that says that the elements of $U(n)$ generate $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Comment: Could you provide a link?